# DESeq2 error when creating the DESeqDataSet

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor

I am trying to create a DESeqDataSet from a SummarizedExperiment. I am getting the error message:

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘assayNames’ for signature ‘"DESeqDataSet"’`

While researching, I found this (verified) example to test with:

```
df=data.frame("treat"=sample(c(80:100),6, replace=FALSE),
              "treat1"=sample(c(90:103),6, replace=FALSE),
              "treat2"=sample(c(80:100),6, replace=FALSE),
              "ctrl"=sample(c(60:90),6, replace=FALSE),
              "ctrl1"=sample(c(60:90),6, replace=FALSE),
              "ctrl2"=sample(c(60:90),6, replace=FALSE))
conds<-as.factor(c("Treat","Treat","Treat","Control","Control","Control"))
coldata <- data.frame(row.names=colnames(df), conds)
dds=DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=df,colData=coldata,design=~conds)
```

Unfortunately, this example gives the same error. I tried the "airway" example, same thing happenend. My sessionInfo() is:

> R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)
>
> locale: [1]
>   en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages: [1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics 
>   grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:  [1] DESeq2_1.10.1
>   RcppArmadillo_0.7.500.0.0  Rcpp_0.12.7
>   SummarizedExperiment_1.4.0 Biobase_2.34.0
>   GenomicRanges_1.26.1        [7] GenomeInfoDb_1.10.0
>   IRanges_2.8.0              S4Vectors_0.12.0
>   BiocInstaller_1.20.3       AnnotationHub_2.2.5
>   BiocGenerics_0.20.0
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] locfit_1.5-9.1
>   lattice_0.20-34              Rsamtools_1.26.1
>   Biostrings_2.42.0            digest_0.6.10                 [6]
>   mime_0.5                     R6_2.2.0                     plyr_1.8.4
>   chron_2.3-47                 acepack_1.4.1                [11]
>   ShortRead_1.28.0             RSQLite_1.0.0                httr_1.2.1
>   ggplot2_2.1.0                zlibbioc_1.20.0              [16]
>   GenomicFeatures_1.26.0       data.table_1.9.6
>   annotate_1.48.0              rpart_4.1-10
>   Matrix_1.2-7.1               [21] splines_3.3.1
>   BiocParallel_1.8.0           geneplotter_1.48.0
>   stringr_1.1.0                foreign_0.8-67               [26]
>   RCurl_1.95-4.8               biomaRt_2.30.0
>   munsell_0.4.3                shiny_0.14.2                 httpuv_1.3.3
>   [31] rtracklayer_1.34.0           htmltools_0.3.5
>   nnet_7.3-12                  gridExtra_2.2.1
>   htmlTable_1.7                [36] interactiveDisplayBase_1.8.0
>   Hmisc_4.0-0                  XML_3.98-1.4
>   GenomicAlignments_1.10.0     bitops_1.0-6                 [41]
>   grid_3.3.1                   xtable_1.8-2                 gtable_0.2.0
>   DBI_0.5-1                    magrittr_1.5                 [46]
>   scales_0.4.0                 stringi_1.1.2
>   XVector_0.14.0               hwriter_1.3.2
>   genefilter_1.52.1            [51] latticeExtra_0.6-28
>   Formula_1.2-1                RColorBrewer_1.1-2           tools_3.3.1 
>   survival_2.40-1              [56] AnnotationDbi_1.36.0
>   colorspace_1.2-7             cluster_2.0.5                knitr_1.14

traceback():

> 11: stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
>           sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
>   10: (function (classes, fdef, mtable) 
>       {
>           methods <- .findInheritedMethods(classes, fdef, mtable)
>           if (length(methods) == 1L) 
>               return(methods[[1L]])
>           else if (length(methods) == 0L) {
>               cnames <- paste0("\"", vapply(classes, as.character, 
>                   ""), "\"", collapse = ", ")
>               stop(gettextf("unable to find an inherited method for function %s for signature %s", 
>                   sQuote(fdef@generic), sQuote(cnames)), domain = NA)
>           }
>           else stop("Internal error in finding inherited methods; didn't return a unique method", 
>               domain = NA)
>       })(list("DESeqDataSet"), function (x, ...) 
>       standardGeneric("assayNames"), )
>   9: assayNames(object)
>   8: "counts" %in% assayNames(object)
>   7: validityMethod(object)
>   6: anyStrings(validityMethod(object))
>   5: validObject(.Object)
>   4: initialize(value, ...)
>   3: initialize(value, ...)
>   2: new("DESeqDataSet", se, design = design)
>   1: DESeqDataSet(se, design = ~cell + dex)

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I recompiled all Bioconductor packages with

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
pkgs <- rownames(installed.packages())
biocLite(pkgs, type="source")
```

and then restarted.